# I am unable to retrieve the updated values in main function

Tags: c, arrays, string

```
//Generating all possible binary strings of lenght 'n' 
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
char a[20];
int ind = 0;
void generateAllBinaryStrings(int n, char **arr,int `i){
 if (i == n){
    printf("%s  \n",a);
    arr[ind] = a;
    ind++;
    return ;
} 

a[i] = '0';
generateAllBinaryStrings(n, arr, i+1); 

a[i] = '1';
generateAllBinaryStrings(n, arr, i+1) ; 

 }

int main(){
 int n = 3,k;   
 char *arr[8];
 generateAllBinaryStrings(n, arr, 0);
 printf("\n");
 for(k=0;k<8;k++)
    printf("%s\n",arr[k]);
return 0;
}
```

// Why this code giving weird output?
   //How to return the array of pointers values updated in another 
    function to main()???

```
//What's wrong with this code?

//output:

cherrycharan@cherrycharan-HP-Notebook:~/Desktop$ ./a.out
 // In generateAllBinaryStrings()
 000  
 001   
 010  
 011  
 100  
 101  
 110  
 111  

 // In main()
 111
 111
 111
 111
 111
 111
 111
 111
```

// Why this code is giving weird output?
  //How to return the array of pointers values updated in another 
  function to main()???

//What's wrong with this code?

Comment: The question is rather what you are trying to do and where you allocate memory for the strings. The code posted doesn't make sense on it's own.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are doing pointer assignment, 
pointers in `arr` will be always pointing to updated contents of `a` that is `111`.

```
arr[ind] = a;
```

Copy the contents instead.

```
arr[ind] = strdup(a);
```

And make sure you `free` afterwards.

Comment: Tq very much. I have  got proper output now.

Comment: So you should mark this answer as such. ;-)

Comment: Rather, if this was the problem, this is just one of endless duplicates where the OP tries to "store data into pointers". Close vote to the linked canonical dupe instead of answering.

Comment: @Lundin I agree you can duplicates, not only for this question but for all the new questions at this stage of Stack overflow.